# How to cast to protocol type in a class?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

This is my code:

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    static var myProperty: Int { get }
}

protocol ProtocolB {}

extension ProtocolB {
    func letsDoSomething() {
        (Self.self as! ProtocolA.Type).myProperty // Works
    }
}

class MyClass {
    func castSelfToProtocolAType() {
        (Self.self as! ProtocolA.Type).myProperty // Doesn't work
        (Self as! ProtocolA.Type).myProperty // Doesn't work also
    }
}
```

How can I cast self in `MyClass` to the dynamic type (like in the protocol extension) `ProtocolA.Type`?

Comment: I think you can use `type(of: self)` to get the dynamic type.

Comment: The code smells quite *objective-c-ish*. Adopt `ProtocolA` in `MyClass` then `MyClass` **is** `ProtocolA` and the compiler tells you to implement `myProperty`. As much as possible do compile time rather than runtime checks.

Comment: `MyClass` is unrelated to `ProtocolA`

Comment: @Carpsen90 yes... But subclasses can implement it :)

Comment: @vadian A subclass may or may not implement the protocol (I am not force casting in my 'real' code, but just to demonstrate the problem)

Comment: These types look really broken. I would start again with your underlying problem. The "but subclasses can implement it" suggests incoherent types. If subclasses implement ProtocolA, then they can use ProtocolA in their own code. If you're using `as?` for this, that's no better than `as!`. It means your types are broken. (To the underlying question, I believe the answer is "Swift can't do this, and that's on purpose.") If Swift has optimized this type to static dispatch, I don't even know how it could compile it.

Answer (score -3):

As per your question,
You are trying to convert your class instance to the protocol type instance, which is not possible because your class does not conform to that protocol.

> **The direct casting from class/struct instance to protocol type
>   instance is not possible, you can only convert to protocol type by
>   accepting that class/struct as a method parameter or by assigning to the other property which protocol type, this is known as
>   implicit type casting.**

Please read this article to understand more about protocols and class types

1. https://medium.com/swift-india/protocol-the-power-of-swift-5dfe9bc41a99
2. https://medium.com/swift-india/protocol-the-power-of-swift-950c85bb69b1
3. https://medium.com/swift-india/protocol-the-power-of-swift-45e97f6531f9
4. https://medium.com/@hitendrahckr/protocol-the-power-of-swift-6906cdedd867
5. https://medium.com/swift-india/protocol-the-power-of-swift-1e5b86bfd1dc

Comment: from what link is that quote?

Comment: Quote was from my side